# Generate openapi 3 shared request and response components with drf-spectacular

Tags: django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-spectacular

Is there a way to generate openapi shared response and request objects using `drf-spectacular`?

In the resulting JSON, I would expect to see `"$ref": "#/components/responses/ErrorResponse"`, not `"$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"`

I've tried using `COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST` config option, but it doesn't seem to be related to my issue.

I've also tried `@extend_schema` annotation to provide custom responses, either inline or as separate objects. They always end up in in the final JSON as part of `/components/schemas/`

Comment: I'm new to this package, but it seems to generate the response inline with the `path`, pointing the schema, and not as a reusable response element . I'm not sure one way is better than the other, since all the /response/ really does is let you package it togeher with examples.  That being said, it would be nice to do that for standard responses (204/400/401/403/whatever) that apply to many endpoints.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your input. I already had the request/response objects defined manualy in Stoplight UI, which provides an easy way to select these reusable responses. I was trying to avoid having to move them to `/schema/` to have the same output as `drf-spectacular`. Too much to explain as to why, just need them to be the same :)

Comment: I have a similar issue with stoplight, but in the opposite direction.  I favor just doing what spectacular does by default, since thats the fight you can't win.  I'm mostly dropping examples except the endpoint specific ones, but still looking for a way to add 'example:' to fields consistently.  I've also written a quite a bit of "hack it" post processing code, but converting a path/response: to a component/response: and handling re-use is too big, I think.

Comment: @Andrew yeah, that's what I ended up doing, defaulting to what spectacular does. Too much of a hassle for little gain to do it otherwise it seems.

Comment: there is no way of using `"#/components/responses/...` at the moment and so using the `schema` section is the default. It is a design choice for a multitude of reasons but the major one is that DRF's flexibility (especially renderers/parsers/pagination) would make this very hard to get right and most likely with a lot more useless duplication.